# How to count, sum, etc. an IList or List

Tags: c#, list, model-view-controller

I'm pretty new to C#. A simplified version of my current problem is:

I have a range of fruit (criteria) and on any given day the change values will be between -1.5 and 2 including 0, or no value (null). This will change from day to day.

```
Fruit     Change
Apple     1.5
Banana    
Grape     0
Lemon     -1
Melon
Pear      2
```

From that data I need to be able to determine 3 values (from those I can then calculate others):

- Sum the available values for Change
- Count the fruit that have Change data (excluding nulls)
- Count the total number of Fruit available (with and without data)

To future proof this, I assume an IList would allow me to one day simply add/remove fruit with a change value and then the above formulas will keep working

I assume I'll need:

```
public string Fruit { get; set; }
public decimal? Change { get; set; }
public decimal? SumChange { get; set; }
public int CountChange { get; set; }
public int CountFruit { get; set; }
```

**My questions are:**

- Which will solve my problem better, a List or an IList and how do I declare/initiate it?
- For that List/IList, how do I set the Change value for a specific Fruit including the Nulls?
- What code do I need to get the 3 values I'm after from the List/IList?

Thanks

Comment: Ignore `IList<T>` - just use `List<T>`.

Comment: You need to read about [generic collection](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/82b15a/generics-and-generic-collections-in-C-Sharp/), [IList and List](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/what-is-the-difference-between-list-and-ilist-in-chash)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `System.Linq`, `System.Collections.Generic`

Here's what you need:

```cs
// Important:
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

static void Main()
{
    List<Fruit> fruits = new List<Fruit>()
    {
        new Fruit() { Name = "Apple", Change = 1.5m },
        new Fruit() { Name = "Banana", Change = null },
        new Fruit() { Name = "Grape", Change = 0m },
        new Fruit() { Name = "Lemon", Change = -1m },
        new Fruit() { Name = "Melon", Change = null },
        new Fruit() { Name = "Pear", Change = 2m },
    };

    decimal? sum_of_changes = fruits.Sum(f => f.Change);
    int fruit_with_change_data = fruits.Count(f => f.Change != null);
    int count_of_all_fruit = fruits.Count();
}
    
public class Fruit
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal? Change { get; set; }
}
```